# What would be the name of this compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, molecular-structure, molecules

[image]

Although I assume this compound is likely unable to be formed, my chemistry teacher put it up on the whiteboard to show the extent of what you can name using IUPAC nomenclature, out of interest I tried to name it and got hexcyclo[2.2.0.0.0]cyclohexane, is this correct or am I mistaken?

Comment: What's up with the central atom? If it's carbon, then you missed something.

Comment: I think the idea my teacher had was that there wasn't a central carbon atom and so each bridge had 0 carbons. I think it was more just a quick drawing so I'm unsure if it's even possible to form but even theoretically I thought it was interesting.

Comment: Well, you either need to fix the drawing so that it makes sense, or sort out the correct structure with your teacher. Neither an incorrectly drawn compound, nor a compound that even you don't know the structure of, can be given a meaningful name.

Comment: @andselisk It is usually drawn that way (albeit incorrectly) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claus%27_benzene

Comment: @Mithoron [Cyclohexane ring with three bridges #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy4lP.png); [cyclohexane ring with three bridges #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bI7h.png). If it is *supposed to* be a cycloxexane, then it should've been drawn correctly (as #1, with the blank space denoting there is *no central atom*). The way OP drew it implies C7 skeleton.

Comment: @andselisk Well, I said it's incorrect, your #1 is better but not more simple. If you checked out the link I put, it's drawn exactly the same and OP provided the context. He all but named it as Clar's benzene.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89342/discussion-between-andselisk-and-mithoron).

Comment: "hexacyclo[2.2.0.0.0]cyclohexane" is an interesting attempt; however "hexa…" is obviously wrong (you should count again), one "cyclo" is enough, and the locants are missing.

Answer (score 10):

I think it is Cubane ($\ce{C8H8}$), a synthetic hydrocarbon molecule ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubane)), which has synthesized using following scheme:

[image: Cubane]

I am confident about that because your teacher had said that there wasn't a central carbon atom (assumingly). See following illstration:

[image: Cubane different angle]

Comment: Well, if someone drawn cubane in this way, it would be downright misleading. Did you read comments?

Comment: @Mithoron: I have read all comments and they were correct about their impressions. I got the idea about cubane with a touch of mechanical drawing. :-)

Comment: Well, while in theory it could be a weirdest pic of cubane, the question is still about nomenclature, not synthesis and I still think the compound is Clar's benzene.

Comment: @Mithoron No one denies the correctness of your opinion: if you would've posted this as a comment, before the question got closed, I'd happily upvoted it.